# Behat Fatal error: Interface 'Behat\Behat\Context\Context' not found

Tags: php, phpstorm, bdd, behat

I am trying to run a Behat feature file after installing and configuring successfully. I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Interface 'Behat\Behat\Context\Context' not found in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\drupal\sites\all\themes\ec_resp\emn_ies_subtheme\vendor\behat\behat\features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php on line 22

Line 22 in FeatureContext.php:

```
class FeatureContext implements Context
```

The Context class is being referenced from:

```
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
```

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

Don't know what is going wrong here as I haven't changed or moved any of the core Behat files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running feature files from the vendor folder?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: So that's your issue. Features should be located in your project's folder. You might try to configure this in behat.yml, but I see no point of running vendor's tests.

Comment: If I copy my features folder into my project folder an then run a feature it has the same effect. `Interface 'Behat\Behat\Context\Context' not found`

Comment: Sounds like and autoload issue. If you are using composer and have installed Behat through composer, try:

`$ composer dump-autoload -o`

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late, but I was facing the same issue. The problem was, that I ran the behat file in the wrong folder.

So my folder structure looks like this:

```
|-project
|
|--tests
|
|---vendor
|
|----bin
|
|-----behat
```

If I try to run the behat file in my project folder like this:

```
[project]$ test/vendor/bin/behat
```

I'll get the error

> `FeatureContext` context class not found and can not be used.

So I have to be in the tests folder then I can run the tests without a Problem.

```
[tests]$ vendor/bin/behat
```

Hopefully it is still answering the question.